# jsoup to search element with the element follow by a tag

Tags: html, jsoup

I would like to use jsoup to search an element starting with the font tag, but return the element of `ul` tag? Please help.

```
<font class="text-error">Error</font>
<ul rel="open" stat="err" ... >
...
</ul>
```

Already tried with the `doc.select([rel=open][stat=err]);`
But needs to look for element that has `<font class="text-error">Error</font>` before it.

Note: font tag can have either Ok or Error value, but looking for prefix of Error, but like to skip the Ok

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the font tag can have Ok instead of Error value, but I need to look for the one with Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the **first** `ul` tag after `font` tag, use this -

```
font+[rel=open][stat=err]
```

If you have **several** `ul`s and they are all siblings, you can get them with -

```
font~[rel=open][stat=err]
```

**EDIT**
To select tags that contains a specific text, like "Error", the selector is -
`font:contains(Error)+[rel=open][stat=err]`

To select tags that do not contains the text "Error" -
`font:not(:contains(Error))+[rel=open][stat=err]`

Comment: Sorry forget to mention I font tag can have either Ok or Error value, but I am  looking for the Error only. Looking for prefix of <font class="text-error">Error</font>, but like to skip the <font class="text-error">Ok</font>